# Multiple File Upload with PHP

Tags: php, html

> i want to upload multiple file upload.It is almost similar like simple
>   file upload but we need to do some modification with html markup and
>   php code. multiple attribute is needed to add on the html markup.
>   Major web browsers like Firefox, Chrome, Safari and IE 9+ support this
>   attribute. I am going to show you how to upload multiple file with PHP
>   and basic HTML form but something missing it (multiple file is not
>   upload)

i tried below code

**HTML CODE**

```
<html>
<head>

<?php

if (isset($message)) {
foreach ($message as $msg) {
printf(“<p class=’status’>%s</p></ br>\n”, $msg);
}
}
# success message
if($count !=0){
printf(“<p class=’status’>%d files added successfully!</p>\n”, $count);
}
?>
<title>Multiple File upload with PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action=”” method=”post” enctype=”multipart/form-data”>
<input type=”file” id=”file” name=”files” multiple=”multiple” accept=”image/*” />
<input type=”submit” value=”Upload!” />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP SCRIPT**

```
<?php
$valid_formats = array(“jpg”, “png”, “gif”, “zip”, “bmp”);
$max_file_size = 1024*5000; //100 kb
$path = “uploads/”; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER[‘REQUEST_METHOD’] == “POST”){
// Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
foreach ($_FILES[‘files’][‘name’] as $f => $name) {
if ($_FILES[‘files’][‘error’][$f] == 4) {
continue; // Skip file if any error found
}
if ($_FILES[‘files’][‘error’][$f] == 0) {
if ($_FILES[‘files’][‘size’][$f] > $max_file_size) {
$message[] = “$name is too large!.”;
continue; // Skip large files
}
elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
$message[] = “$name is not a valid format”;
continue; // Skip invalid file formats
}
else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[“files”][“tmp_name”][$f], $path.$name))
$count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
}
}
}
}

?>
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace input file name like `files[]` not like `files` see following form example:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload!" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank You @sameer  now it' working.

Answer (score 1):

Use `files[]` into `<input>` name attaribute

```
 <input type=”file” id=”file” name=”files[]” multiple=”multiple” accept=”image/*” />
```

We also need to give file input type file name with box breaks like `files[]` and need to add a property named `multiple`. Here `accept` is an optional property that used to allow users to upload only image files.