# Upload multiple files in PHP failed

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to upload multiple files in a single submit button using PHP but its not working and i had tried upload a single file using php and it was working well so i thought that it would be good to just copy the same code for the second file to have two files uploaded but in vain.

i had tried this solution on SO but i had no success :[solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php)

[solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941592/php-multiple-file-array)

[solution3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129388/multiple-file-upload-with-php)

```
    <form action="" method="post" target="frame" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
        <div class="buttonsend">
            <p>Entrez votre fichier.cfg :</p>
            <input type = "file" name = "cfg" /></br>
            <p>Entrez votre fichier.dat :</p>
            <input type = "file" name = "dat" /></br></br> 
            <button id="send" type="submit" name="send">Générer</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
            $file_tmpcfg = $_FILES['cfg']['tmp_name'];
            $file_namecfg = $_FILES['cfg']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmpcfg,"/home/imagesdcard/www/".$file_namecfg);
            $file_tmpdat = $_FILES['dat']['tmp_name'];
            $file_namedat = $_FILES['dat']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmpdat,"/home/imagesdcard/www/".$file_namedat);
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: What happens when try? Do you get an error? Does nothing happen?

Comment: What output do you get if you do a var_dump( $_FILES ); inside your if statement?

Comment: var_dump($_FILES) didn't output anything , is it normal ? maybe i have to set something on my php.ini

Comment: It should output something.  The code seems fine. Which browser are you using?

Comment: im using firefox and lighttpd.

Comment: This is probably related to lightpd and not the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine. I printed uploaded files and it didnt show any error.

```
        <form action="" method="post" target="frame" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    <div class="buttonsend">
        <p>Entrez votre fichier.cfg :</p>
        <input type = "file" name = "cfg" /></br>
        <p>Entrez votre fichier.dat :</p>
        <input type = "file" name = "dat" /></br></br> 
        <button id="send" type="submit" name="send">Générer</button>
    </div>
</form>

<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

    $uploaddir = '/var/www/html/';
    $uploadfileCfg = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['cfg']['name']);
    $uploadfileDat = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['dat']['name']);

    echo "<p>";

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cfg']['tmp_name'], $uploadfileCfg)) {
      echo "File cfg is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n<br>";
    }else{
        echo "File cfg is invalid";
    }
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['dat']['tmp_name'], $uploadfileDat)) {
      echo "File dat is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n<br>";
    }else{
        echo "File dat is invalid";
    }

    echo "</p>";
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Here is some more debugging info:<br>';
    print_r($_FILES);
    print "</pre>";
}
?>
```

result:

```
File cfg is valid, and was successfully uploaded. 
File dat is valid, and was successfully uploaded. 

Here is some more debugging info:
Array
(
    [cfg] => Array
        (
            [name] => 102440.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpQdhjY0
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 72469
        )

    [dat] => Array
        (
            [name] => 1plus1.pem
            [type] => application/x-x509-ca-cert
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpId9rW1
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 1692
        )

)
```

Comment: But when i tried to check in the path if the file is existed or not, i learned that the files uploaded wasn't there so i figured that something is wrong with my code.

Comment: might be but as you asked about uploading files issue, that is solved.